# Can't split webpage text and image using grid (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to programming and I'm creating a webpage for fun I have most of my desired results however I'm trying to have the image on the right hand side and the text on the left. I have tried floating the image right and trying (top:) to push it up but that doesn't seem to do anything. any help would be much appreciated. a photo will be provided of the websites current state and my current code.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-content {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.top-content img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-bar a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.author {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 70%;
    left: 43%;
    transform: translate(-50, -6);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.photo img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.main-content {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 400px);
}

.main-content h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/practice3.css">
        <title>practice3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="top-content">
                <ul class="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="./imgs/helping.jpg" alt="photo">
                <div class="author">
                <h1>ARC Ulster green</h1>
                <h3>Always there, Always Caring</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="main-content">
                <h1>We Strive to touch hearts</h1>
                <h3 class="two">Each and every day</h3>
                <p>Since the begining our support staff have shown
                a dedication to helping people and bettering their lifes.
                and as a consiquence our individuals feel more confident 
                and happy than ever. As we continue our mission to help those
                who need it we have seen our individuals prosper to become
                independent living in the community among the rest of the world.
                we are proud to serve our community not only because we care, but also 
                because we want to see our individuals live long happy lives
                with joy and laughter while they learn valuable skills in the proccess.
                everyday our staff walks into their job site ready, willing, and
                confident that they will complete their mission to provide
                the best care around and that is an ARC gaurentee. as we always 
                strive to beat expectations and go above and beyond for those in our care.
                 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="photo">
                <img src="./imgs/staff.jpg" alt="staff">
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: current page]

Comment: `main{display:flex;}` would be a start instead float.

Comment: okay ill try it!!

Comment: i added it to my img (.photo img) and it didint change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> earlier comment : `main{display:flex;}` would be a start instead float.

here is the flex display with a few fix :

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.top-content {
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.top-content img {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative; 
}

.nav-bar li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.author {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.photo { 
}

.photo img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contains;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 2;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  margin: auto;  
  min-height:400px;
}

.main-content h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-content">
    <ul class="nav-bar">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1027/200/400.jpg?hmac=YJeQQGOomEy2UFSz-q6NCey-QQwgmugsBRRlhCjfCB0" alt="photo">
    <div class="author">
      <h1>ARC Ulster green</h1>
      <h3>Always there, Always Caring</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h1>We Strive to touch hearts</h1>
    <h3 class="two">Each and every day</h3>
    <p>Since the begining our support staff have shown a dedication to helping people and bettering their lifes. and as a consiquence our individuals feel more confident and happy than ever. As we continue our mission to help those who need it we have seen
      our individuals prosper to become independent living in the community among the rest of the world. we are proud to serve our community not only because we care, but also because we want to see our individuals live long happy lives with joy and laughter
      while they learn valuable skills in the proccess. everyday our staff walks into their job site ready, willing, and confident that they will complete their mission to provide the best care around and that is an ARC gaurentee. as we always strive
      to beat expectations and go above and beyond for those in our care.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1027/200/400.jpg?hmac=YJeQQGOomEy2UFSz-q6NCey-QQwgmugsBRRlhCjfCB0" alt="staff">
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put display:flex (will set the direction automatically to flex-row) on the main:

```
main{
  display: flex;
}
```

and if you delete width:25% from .photo img you'll see the full image

Comment: tha's about my comment, but looks like it was misunderstood ...